# How can I count the total number of empty cells across all dimensions in Tableau?

Tags: null, cell, tableau-api, isnull

I would like to analyze if our project managers have filled out all data attributes in a table (milestones, estimated costs etc.). We have more than 100 attributes. We want to use Tableau to visualize this by simply comparing the total number of empty cells to the total number of cells (and then filter by project manager). Ideally, it would want something super easy like Ratio = [number of blank cells]/[total number of cells]. So my question is:

**Is there an easy way to count the total number of empty cells in an entire table, without having to type in all 100 dimensions?**

I currently use:

```
SUM(if ISNULL([dimension1]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

But that only gives me the number of empty cells in dimension1. Is there an elegant way to include all dimensions?

Also, I am looking for a way to find the total number of cells (blank and filled) in a data table. Something like the 'Number of Records' measure, but for cells. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: FYI, the INT() function converts True to 1 and False to 0 for boolean arguments. So the expression SUM(INT(ISNULL([dimension1]))) is equivalent to the one you showed. Clearly more compact, and - when you get used to it - I think more readable. Especially when the boolean conditions get more complex

Comment: FYI, another alternative is to recall that COUNT([dimension1]) returns the number of records that had a non-null value for [dimension1]. So you could also use COUNT("*") - COUNT([dimension1]) to find the number of records with a null value for [dimension1]

Answer (score 0):

Reshape your data and this becomes easy. The Tableau pivot functionality may work for you to do this. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.htm

This will convert the dimensions to one field and then you will be able to count the nulls as per your formula above.